# Doctrine findOneBy simple_array property isn't returning a valid match

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have an entity LongBeachClickerUploadBallotOption that contains a simple_array property $publicComments:

```
/**
 * @var array
 * @ORM\Column(name="public_comments", type="simple_array", nullable=true)
 */
protected $publicComments;
```

When I instantiate a new object and give it multiple publicComments, and then try to query for that object, doctrine does not seem to return a match:

```
$lbBallotOption = new LongBeachClickerUploadBallotOption('AMPC', array('1', '2', '3'));
$this->em->persist($lbBallotOption);
$this->em->flush();

dump($lbBallotOption->getPublicComments());

$bo = $this->em->getRepository('VoteBundle:LongBeachClickerUploadBallotOption')
    ->findOneBy(array('motion' => 'AMPC', 'publicComments' => array('1', '2', '3')));

dump($bo);

$bo = $this->em->getRepository('VoteBundle:LongBeachClickerUploadBallotOption')
    ->findOneBy(array('motion' => 'AMPC', 'publicComments' => array(1, 2, 3)));

dump($bo);
exit;
```

This code outputs the following:

```
HearingVoteImport.php on line 258:
array:3 [▼
  0 => "1"
  1 => "2"
  2 => "3"
]
HearingVoteImport.php on line 263:
null
HearingVoteImport.php on line 268:
null
```

What's going on here? I tried querying both with integer "strings" and true ints just out of curiosity.

According to Doctrine's SimpleArrayType, it should implode these values with a ',' and then I would assume just do a string match... The rows in the database I can see are storing properly:

```
id    motion   public_comments
109   AMPC     1,2,3
```

Edit:
I added SQL Logging:

```
$this->em->getConnection()->getConfiguration()->setSQLLogger(new \Doctrine\DBAL\Logging\EchoSQLLogger());
```

and it outputs the following:

```
  SELECT t0.id AS id1, 
  t0.motion AS motion2, 
  t0.public_comments AS public_comments3 
  FROM lb_clicker_upload_ballot_option t0 
  WHERE t0.motion = ? AND t0.public_comments IN (?) LIMIT 1 
  array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "AMPC" [1]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "2" [2]=> string(1) "3" } } 
  array(2) { [0]=> string(6) "string" [1]=> int(102) }
```

And of course, as mentioned in the first response, I tried querying like this:

```
$bo = $this->em->getRepository('VoteBundle:LongBeachClickerUploadBallotOption')
        ->findOneBy(array('motion' => 'AMPC', 'publicComments' => "1,2,3"));
```

only for it to complain:

Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed

Comment: I suspect I will need to just use query builder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know the question is quite old, but since I stumbled across the same issue... The SQL Logging was quite helpful.

The problem is, that in `public_comments` a string of comma separated strings is stored in the database. This string has to be found in the array given to the `IN` keyword. Since in this array the values are separate and not concatenated to a string as in `public_comments` the `IN` operator can't find the string.

I circumvented the issue by preparing the `$search` array as

```
$public_comments = array(1, 2, 3);
$search = array(implode(',', $public_comments));

$repo = $this->em->getRepository('VoteBundle:LongBeachClickerUploadBallotOption');

$bo = $repo->findOneBy(array('motion' => 'AMPC', 'publicComments' => $search));
```

The wrapping `array()` is needed to avoid the observed complaints about the invalid arguments in implode. I'd say it's a bug in handling of simple_array in a search context.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Old question notwithstanding.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you have to [query array fields like a standard text field](http://doctrine-dbal.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/types.html#simple-array).
So imloding an array is an easiest way to go.